# Converting Doom maps to JSON

Tags: javascript, html5, html-canvas

This is a really cool demo of a Canvas Doom Engine made back in 2006:

http://canvex.lazyilluminati.com/84/play.xhtml

Here is the e1m1 map in JSON format:

http://canvex.lazyilluminati.com/84/map1.js

Does anyone know of the tool used to convert Doom maps into JSON? I can't imagine this was done by hand :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a Python script that converts MAP data from a WAD to JSON: https://github.com/nicokruger/py-wad2json

Combine that with Unwad, a utility that extracts all other data from a WAD: https://code.google.com/p/unwad

Answer (score 6):

It probably was not done by hand, but as the [WAD file format](http://doom.wikia.com/wiki/WAD) is pretty well documented it was probably relatively easy to write a one-off tool to perform the conversion. It's possible one of the [WAD editors](http://doom.wikia.com/wiki/Choosing_a_WAD_editor) floating around have the functionality buried away, but I suspect that the author used a tool he wrote himself (and has not released) in this case.

The JSON structures and arrays used in the linked JSON file don't seem to correspond directly to the lump types in the WAD file, which suggests a custom tool to me. It looks like some of his maps aren't direct ports of DOOM maps either (at least none I recognize) so it's possible he's using an internal map building tool instead of just an internal JSON conversion tool.

The author's email is at the bottom of his [homepage](http://canvex.lazyilluminati.com/). You'd probably get a better response if you ask him directly.